Hide the start, stop buttons and progress bar using whatever it takes
I want to put a video on the first view on the page, but i find it difficult because
everytime the page is laoding, the start, stop buttons and progressive bar.
the problem is that they show up when it's loading and it disappear when it's done loading....
Do you guys have any clue on how to completely hide the start, stop buttons and progressive bar??
I've tried so many CSS styles such as
video::-webkit-media-controls {display: none;} & video::-moz-media-controls{display: none;}

I'm expecting the site to load without showing any of the controls tools.
This is my code for the player:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<video width="640" height="480" controls>
<source src="my_video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

</body>
</html>

thanks

Hi. (1) It's not clear what you mean because you did not show code of your player. I have added some example code but you need to fix it by adding your own code. Edit by using the edit option... (2) Is it possible to make an example demo page and then give us the link to check problem?
